# Nativebase how to customize Button color in theme without using colorScheme?

Tags: react-native, native-base, theming

I really struggle with this simple thing.

By default the button color is `primary.600` which is not the real primary color. So I just want it to be `primary.400` (the real primary).

As there is nearly no documentation on this and to my regret no IDE auto-completion with typescript, I am asking your lights on how to solve the problem

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
export const theme = extendTheme({
    components: {
        Button: {
            // I tried this after checking directly in ts file for extendTheme implementation
            baseStyle: () => ({
                bg: 'red.500',
                backgroundColor: 'red.500',
            })
            // as well as
            baseStyle:  {
                bg: 'red.500',
                backgroundColor: 'red.500',
            }
            // also tried with hex colors with no success
        },
        // Also tried the code in this example: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/v3.1.0/src/theme/components/button.ts#L72 with no success
        variants: {
            solid(props: Dict) {
                const { colorScheme: c } = props;
                let bg = `${c}.400`
                bg = mode(bg, `${c}.400`)(props);
                if (props.isDisabled) {
                    bg = mode(`muted.300`, `muted.500`)(props);
                }

                const styleObject = {
                    _web: {
                        outlineWidth: 0,
                    },
                    bg,
                    _hover: {
                        bg: mode(`${c}.600`, `${c}.500`)(props),
                    },
                    _pressed: {
                        bg: mode(`${c}.700`, `${c}.600`)(props),
                    },
                };

                return styleObject;
            }
    }
});
```

Also tried the code in this example: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/v3.1.0/src/theme/components/button.ts#L72 with no success

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to define the specific color, only a `colorScheme`. This may be because the button as designed in NativeBase relies on a set of colors, not a single one (normal, disabled, hovering, pressed, etc.).

That being said I can see two approaches to achieving your goal.

1. define a custom color scene and connect it to the button in the theme configuration:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    custom: {
      50: '#ecfeff',
      100: '#67e8f9',
      200: '#22d3ee',
      300: '#06b6d4',
      400: '#0891b2',
      500: '#0e7490',
      600: '#155e75',
      700: '#164e63',
      800: '#174e63',
      900: '#184e63',
    },
  },
  components: {
    Button: {
      defaultProps: {
        colorScheme: 'custom',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

2. Simply override the primary theme (this could of course have side effects if you use the primary color in other components)

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    primary: {
      50: '#ecfeff',
      100: '#67e8f9',
      200: '#22d3ee',
      300: '#06b6d4',
      400: '#0891b2',
      500: '#0e7490',
      600: '#155e75',
      700: '#164e63',
      800: '#174e63',
      900: '#184e63',
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  baseStyle: {
    rounded: 'md',
    bg: '#ffcc00',
    backgroundColor: '#fc0',
  },
```

Using bg and backgroundColor seems to work

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, could you show more of the code please, for my case this particularly doesn't work for the Button. I tried what you showed but I may have made a mistake with context...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).